# Spring 3: Do something when index.jsp is loaded

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Is this possible?
When I go to the index.jsp I want a file to be rewritten...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could write a Filter which will be invoked whenever a request for index.jsp comes in. This filter would be called before loading the index.jsp page. Here's a link for a tutorial on Filters

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/tutorial-java-servlet-filter-example-using-eclipse-apache-tomcat/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a Spring-y way to do so is to define an [interceptor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-handlermapping-interceptor) and then [configure](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-interceptors) it for the specified URL:

The interceptor class would be something like:

```
public class RewriteInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {
// implementation
}
```

and the configuration would like:

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <mvc:interceptor>
        <mapping path="/index.jsp"/>
        <bean class="your.path.RewriteInteceptor" />
</mvc:interceptor> </mvc:interceptors>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is index.jsp a view that is presented after a user has requested a specific url eg http://example.com/context/home ?

If so in your Controller request mapping for /home you can just do what you need there.

Comment: how can I map to index.jsp..? its not in a view-folder but directly in WebContent